# jquery form not printing input

Tags: javascript, jquery

Found a nice website for an alternative to using /forms in share point.  My code below though does not print my input to the screen. Any Suggestions.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function printvalues() 
    {
        var div = document.getElementById("divId");
        div.innerHTML += "test";
        div.innerHTML += inputobj1.value;
    }
</script>

<div id="divId">
    username: <input name="inputobj1" value="" />

    <button id="idButton" type="button" onclick ="printvalues();">
        Generate!
    </button>

    <div id="divId">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's two issues with your code.

First, you're missing a closing `</div>` tag; **and** you have two `<div>` elements with the same `id` property! I think you should remove the first div's `id` property.

Second, your `<input />` is missing the `id` property, therefore it's not automatically defined by `inputobj1`.

Try this markup:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function printvalues() {
        var div = document.getElementById("divId");
        div.innerHTML += "test";
        div.innerHTML += document.getElementById("inputobj1").value;
    }
</script>
<div>
    username: <input id="inputobj1" name="inputobj1" value="" />

    <button id="idButton" type="button" onclick ="printvalues();">Generate!</button>

    <div id="divId"></div>
</div>
```

Here's a [working jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fSHNT/1/).

Answer (score 0):

```
this doesnst work because you have two div with id="idButton" and your markup is not closed
```

this may also work as you tagged jquery

```
function printvalues() {
  var value = $('input[name="inputobj1"]').val();
  var $div = $('<div>',{text:value});
  $('#divId').append($div);
}
```

or using the divId div

```
function printvalues() {
  var value = $('input[name="inputobj1"]').val();
  $('#divId').text(value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function printvalues() {
        var div = document.getElementById("divId");
        div.innerHTML += "test";
        div.innerHTML += inputobj1.value;
        }
</script>
<div id="divId2">
    username: <input name="inputobj1" value="" />

<button id="idButton" type="button" onclick ="javascript:printvalues();">
  Generate!
  </button>

<div id="divId"></div>
</div>
```

or

```
<div id="divId2">
    username: <input name="inputobj1" value="" />

<button id="idButton" type="button">
  Generate!
  </button>

<div id="divId"></div>
</div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function printvalues() {
        var div = document.getElementById("divId");
        div.innerHTML += "test";
        div.innerHTML += inputobj1.value;
        }
        $('#idButton').click(function(){
            printvalues()
        })
</script>
```

You had 2 divId's as well, i made an assumption on witch on to use